# get name for dynamic created labels with a existing button on the form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a `Label` *dynamiclly* on my windows form like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { 
    Text = dr["name"].ToString(),
    Name = string.Format("test_{0}", i) 
  }, 1, i);
}
```

now what I have `Button` in my form when I click on it I want it to display the `Text` in the `Label`:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(test_1.Text); // <- Compile time error here
}
```

but it says `test_1` *does not exist*.
Which I understand why since its dynamically made; but is it possible for me to achieve this?

Comment: [TableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcontrolfromposition)

Comment: You should *find* the `Label`, e.g. `Label myLabel = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("test_1", true).OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of *runtime* created `Control` (`Label` in your case) you have to *find* it. You can do it with a pinch of *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ... 

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Label testLabel = tableLayoutPanel1
     .Controls
     .Find("test_1", true)
     .OfType<Label>()
     .FirstOrDefault();

   MessageBox.Show(testLabel?.Text ?? "Label not found");
 }
```

Comment: tableLayoutPanel1.Controls["test_1"].Text